# Access RAID configuration in x3550M2

Tags: raid, ibm-xseries

I'm trying to configure RAID in a IBM x3550 M2 server. I can't find any messages on boot about any hotkey to access the configuration utility. I wasn't able either in BIOS.

The card is a on board LSI 1068e. I can't find the original CD's shipped with the server, but I downloaded Server Guide 9.21 from IBM web. Booted with that, and only getting stuck at "Windows loading"p. Tried with a 8.? version from a x3550 (M1), but it was less useful.

Although I do not consider myself an expert, I'm starting to feel like a newbie luser. Any help?

Comment: Is the on board LSI 1068e HW RAID or just SAS? The <A href="http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/systems/support/system_x_pdf/00d3099.pdf">manual</a> I just checked mentioned several options, not all of them HW RAID.

Comment: Right now is configured as RAID1, so I guess it's hardware RAID. In BIOS I can't find either information. I had to use the already installed ESXi to gather the information. Didn't mention before but I tried already Ctrl+C combination as stated in the linked manaul

Answer (score 3):

Finally found it. It's clearly explained in the User's Guide, but I was focused on searching "RAID" in that guide. As soon as I searched "LSI" (Hennes's comment switched on the light), I found it in the "Starting the LSI Configuration Utility program" chapter. The path is (from BIOS): System Settings → Adapters and UEFI drivers → Please refresh this page on the first visit → LSI Controller.

It's not the most intuitive GUI, but there is it.